# Link not passing state to component in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass state with a React Router Link tag:

```
  <Link to={{
          pathname: `/edit/${row.id}`,
          state: { data: row }
        }}>
          <Edit size={14} className='mr-50' />
        </Link>
```

but when I try to access `this.props` in the edit component, it's undefined.

EDIT: row is an existing object

EDIT 2:

App.js

```
 <BrowserRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <ProtectedRoute exact path="/contributor/edit/:rawContentId" component={ContributorEditPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

And inside the `ContributorEditPage` which is a class component, I have a function that is attached to an `onClick` event and has `this.props.history.push('/').

EDIT 3:
I'm not sure if this can be the problem because till now I though that `EditComponent` was a parent but I have a function:

```
const withLayout = Page => {
    
    return () => (
        <div>
            <Header />
                <Page/>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

export default withLayout;
```

and I export every component:

```
export default withLayout(EditPage);
```

Comment: `but when I try to access this.props in the edit component, it's undefined.` What exactly? `this.props` is undefined? It shouldn't be, there should be at least `size` and `className`.

Comment: If you are using a functional component, this.props will be undefined. Can you please update the question with the full code if possible.

Comment: I've added my route config in App.js. ProtectedRoute is  just a function that returns `Route`

Comment: @tkausl this.props is completely empty and I'm not sure why as I have the Route wrapped inside a `BrowserRouter` tag

Comment: are you using function component or class components? props.location.state should be possible no ?

Comment: @MaximeGhéraille I've updated the question and have added something that I didn't notice. Not sure if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to access it via `props.location.state` if you dont forget to add props as param to your component.

here is an [example](https://medium.com/@bopaiahmd.mca/how-to-pass-props-using-link-and-navlink-in-react-router-v4-75dc1d9507b4)

Answer (score -1):

It depends how your component is, however you could use HOC called `withRouter` to have access to location props

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter